# Why getting “Resource has been exhausted” although the usage is within the quota limit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client, quota

### The problem

I'm using Google Sheets API v4 from node.js (Cloud Functions for Firebase) via `googleapis` npm package to write to the Google Sheets.

Getting this error sporadically:

```
Error: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).
    at Gaxios._request (/workspace/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:89:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

It doesn’t say which particular quota is reached, though.

At that particular moment, indeed, there were many concurrent function executions that write to the Google Sheets, and several of them failed:
[image: Failed executions]

### GCP console

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas says that the quota statuses are fine:
[image: Quotas]

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/quotas shows that the usage at the moment of issue is within the quota limits:
[image: Read requests per 100 sec]
[image: Write requests per 100 sec]

### The guess

I'm suspecting that I may reach the “Write requests per 100 seconds **per user**” quota limit… because the “traffic by response code” chart shows 2.03 reqs/sec, which gives 203 requests per 100 seconds, and all of them from one credential:
[image: Traffic]

However “Per-user quota usage is not displayed”, and neither error message or GCP console give definite indication on what is the actual quota being exhausted.

Also, there is a counter-argument to this guess: **total** “requests per 100 seconds” in the chart above is below 100, and I presume that “requests per 100 seconds **per user**” cannot be higher than total.

### The questions

1. Is my conclusion based on the charts in the GCP console correct that I’m not reaching the quota limits?
2. How to figure out which quota limit is referred to in the error message?
3. What other cause can be there behind `Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)` error?

---

### Update based on the comment

Here are the links to the actual code repository.

- The cloud function that is triggered: the [line that calls my repository class method](https://github.com/PureBhaktiArchive/audioseva/blob/master/functions/src/TrackEditing/TE.functions.ts#L216).
- The [repository method itself](https://github.com/PureBhaktiArchive/audioseva/blob/25d1a50214173f5fa23454bf19e85a648ba8cd85/functions/src/AbstractRepository.ts#L106) that calls the `Spreadsheet` class method to update the rows.
- The [Spreadsheet method](https://github.com/PureBhaktiArchive/audioseva/blob/25d1a50214173f5fa23454bf19e85a648ba8cd85/functions/src/Spreadsheet.ts#L386) which prepares data for updating/appending.
- Actual [method that calls the `googleapis`](https://github.com/PureBhaktiArchive/audioseva/blob/25d1a50214173f5fa23454bf19e85a648ba8cd85/functions/src/Spreadsheet.ts#L347).

This is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is the actual code used. I don't think providing a reproducible example is worth time in this case, because the question is primarily related to interpreting the error message and figuring out which particular quota limit has been reached.

Comment: Can we see your current script for replicating the issue?

Comment: I've added the repository links to the question, and restructured the text to be clear on what are the questions actually.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. In my experience, when Sheets API is used in a loop, I confirmed that such error occurs even when the remaining quotas are enough. So I wanted to confirm it. But from your script, I couldn't confirm it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. In my code each function instance does only one batch update, however the number of instances is high. I guess it may be of the same effect as in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I guess it may be of the same effect as in a loop.`, when your issue was resolved by modifying it, I'm glad.

Comment: @AKd did you manage to solve this issue? If so, could you please share the solution you found?

Comment: The mystery of the quota limit is still not revealed…I have worked around this issue by optimizing my code. Particularly, by limiting the number of concurrent instances of the cloud function that writes to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Glad to read you managed to get  a workaround, but if the issue is still there, I strongly suggest to open an Issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) of GCP under **private** components (`Public Trackers > Cloud Platform > Compute > App Engine > Private App Engine issues`), so you can share your project Id and sensitive information. It is very likely you are hitting a Quota not visible for you, so, in the end, you would end up requesting a Quota Increase.